# replace upper case with lower case regexes without \L

Tags: regex

I have browse through the web even here, I am not seeing what i am looking for.

I want to search and replace all link url containing uppercase and space with lower case without putting the \L before the $1.

i.e any uppercase found within, starting and ending of the link will be replaced with lowercase.

```
<a href="https://example.com/check/Happy frend/"> => <a href="https://example.com/check/happy-frend/">
<a href="https://example.com/check/Happy Frend/"> => <a href="https://example.com/check/happy-frend/">
<a href="https://example.com/check/HAppy frend/"> => <a href="https://example.com/check/happy-frend/">
```

etc all the text after **check** with be replaced with lower case text then including replacing the space with minus sign to it.

is there any way to do this without using the `\L$1` on the replace string, instead i just need only **$1** to be the replace substitute.

Comment: Its just a plugin in wp

Comment: Please do mention why using `\L` is posing a problem for you? If it is not the problem; then you can use something like [**this**](https://regex101.com/r/ViTq0C/1)

Comment: I think \L is a problem, I only need something like $1,$2 and so on

Comment: Because it won't take changes instead it will write L in ever single text.

Comment: I have tried the \\L but it still brings LHappy-friend on the permalink

Comment: Please look at [**this**](https://onlinegdb.com/rJF3snXj8) code. I pretty sure you're working with `php`. Read the comment properly in the  mentioned code

Comment: I know the code you sent is suppose to work as normal. But it seems like the plugin author limited the replacement values to only $1 2 3 etc. So I am just looking for anyway it can be done without the /L in on the back of $1